# How if statement is always returning true in Umbraco custom controller?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, umbraco, umbraco7

I have the following foreach loop admittedly not the best solution (using a model within the loop) however will work on best practice/performance at a later date but just wanting to get it working IF possible.

I can confirm the postAuthor is receiving a model and is not null, the comparison of the two int values are equal although I am not sure how to output the values to console or something (c# noob).

I just seem to be getting all the results rather than only the posts that have the same author id as the currently selected author.

Any advice/help would be appreciated.

```
        foreach (var post in posts)
        {
            var postAuthor = new AuthorModel(umbracoHelper.TypedContent(authorId), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, umbracoHelper);
            int postAuthorId = postAuthor.AuthorId;

            if (postAuthorId != authorId)
            {
                posts.Remove(post);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where is the definition of authorId used in the if statement?

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado is outside of the loop as the variable will not change but authorId equals the current model (int authorId = authorModel.AuthorId;)

Comment: To write on the console: `Console.WriteLine(valueString);` - https://www.dotnetperls.com/console

Answer (score 2):

You have your for loop. Within this for loop, the two statements

```
var postAuthor = new AuthorModel(umbracoHelper.TypedContent(authorId), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, umbracoHelper);
int postAuthorId = postAuthor.AuthorId;
```

shouldn't be placed there : they do not depend on your var post, so at each iteration, they will have the same values.

Your if statement compares postAuthorId (which value is always the same as I said before) with authorId, which is not assigned to any value inside of the for loop.

What you probably want to do is something like :

```
if (postAuthorId != post.authorId) {//do stuff}
```

I don't understand the purpose of your code : postAuthorId will always equals authorId since you defined the first one using the second one.

Your seem to have "misthought" your code.

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that the following code looks for an Umbraco entity with the given **node id**:

```
umbracoHelper.TypedContent(authorId)
```

So your variable `authorId` refers to a node id and I assume `postAuthorId` refers to a property on your AuthorModel, hence the difference in results.

Probably if you changed your code to the following, it should work

```
foreach (var post in posts)
{
        // Assuming post is an IPublishedContent
        var postAuthor = new AuthorModel(post, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, umbracoHelper);
        int postAuthorId = postAuthor.AuthorId;

        if (postAuthorId != authorId)
        {
            posts.Remove(post);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might get an error because you change the collection you are looping over. Solve it by collecting the posts that *match* in *another* collection.